# Prevent code execution from xml and other text files

Tags: xml, security, flask, xss, code-injection

I'm writing a website in Flask that allows users to upload and then view text files (JSON and XML). I send JSON files with a `Content-type` header of `application/json` and I send XML with `application/xml`.

After the file has been uploaded from the form, I process the name using [`secure_filename()`](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/utils/#werkzeug.utils.secure_filename). I save the file to the server using the [`save()`](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/datastructures/#werkzeug.datastructures.FileStorage.save) method on the file object. The files are saved to a directory on my server. Otherwise, I do not process the files; it is important that the xml tags remain intact for the purposes of my project since later on the users may choose to parse the files.

To serve the files back to the user, I use [`send_from_directory`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#flask.send_from_directory).

My question is, is this design vulnerable to XSS or code injection and, if so, how do I prevent such attacks?

Comment: What do people do with the downloaded JSON and XML files?

Comment: Users can view them or choose to process them with my application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, your design is not vulnerable to XSS attacks. At no point do you use *any* user-supplied content in generating your web pages themselves.

The content passes through our site as a black box instead; from browser to your filesystem, then back to other HTTP clients that may choose to download the content again.

The filename you control entirely, you never read the contents of the file, you never take any of the file contents and put them into generated HTML content.

The only problem that may exist is that someone uploads a file that is not XML or JSON, really, but a file that exploits a vulnerability in whatever the downloader uses to parse the file. That's not a XSS attack however.

Comment: By "whatever the downloader uses," do you mean something the browser used to display these files?

Comment: If the browser displayes XML but has a vulnerability in the XML parser then that could be exploited by uploading a malicious XML file, but that is not XSS and not your service's fault.